# How to calculate key through the message and the generated Mac

Tags: java, encryption, java-8, cryptography

I'd like to know if there is a way to get a key through the message and the MAC generated by applying an algorithm for decryption (which is SHA1) to the message along with the key, but the key does not know it, how could I do? I have an example that computes the MAC randomly, which is as follows:

```
public class MACApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //if(args.length < 1) System.out.println("Úsese MACApp \"hola\"");
        //else performMACTest(args[0]);
        performMACTest("Hola");
    }

    public static void performMACTest(String s) {
        try {
            // Elegimos el algoritmo de hashing

            String alg = "HmacMD5";
            // Creamos un objeto Mac que implementa el algoritmo especificado
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(alg);
            // Construimos un genrador de claves privadas
            KeyGenerator generador = KeyGenerator.getInstance(alg);
            // Creamos una clave privada con el generador de claves

            SecretKey clavePrivada = generador.generateKey();
            mac.init(clavePrivada);
            // Pasamos la cadena de caracteres a un array de bytes y lo procesamos
            // con el algoritmo del Mac, es decir, procesamos (de manera indirecta) el
            // string que hemos pasado como parámetro
            mac.update(s.getBytes());
            // Indicamos que ya hemos acabado y recogemos el resultado
            byte[] b = mac.doFinal();
            System.out.println("\nMensaje original: " + s);
            System.out.println("\nMAC    :" + Conversor.aCadenaDeHexadecimales(b));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Conversor {
    public static String[] digitos =
            {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"};

    public static String aCadenaDeHexadecimales(byte[] array) {
        String cadena = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
            cadena = cadena + convertirUno(array[i]);
        return cadena;
    }

    private static String convertirUno(byte valor) {
        int n = valor;
        if (n < 0) n = 256 + n;
        int d1 = n / 16;
        int d2 = n % 16;
        return digitos[d1] + digitos[d2];
    }
}
```

If someone I could help find the key. I put an example:

> Message: 231456789 487654 500
>
> MAC: 5807a9647ed99e98b8d197e608c1de8bcffa571f

The type of Hash to encrypt/decrypt is SHA1 and also the size of the key is 24 bits, i.e. must have 3 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Getting the key is like finding the holy grail for attackers; if you get the key then everything encrypted or protected by that key is basically broken. So although there are many issues with ciphers and other primitives such as those used for hash functions, getting the key is generally not possible.

HMAC is build upon a secure, **one way** hash function. As the function is one way it should be impossible to retrieve the key value without brute forcing it. And this is the case even for HMAC-MD5 and HMAC-SHA1 - i.e. a MAC functions build upon a largely broken hash function.

You can try until the worlds end but you won't be able to retrieve the key - nor the holy grail for that matter.

Comment: Is there no way to get the key or size of the key? It's that I have to do it for a faculty job, to have if there is any online tool that can do it

Comment: Well, the size of the key is 128 bits, as the key size is identical to the output size of the hash. For getting the key value itself, well, no.

Comment: Good, the size of the key tells me the statement that is 24 bits, what I want to know is how you could calculate that key, if it is safe that size and the minimum time it would take to find the key approximately.
Thank you!!

Comment: SHA-1, MD5, no key size in the code and then 24 bit suddenly comes up. Sheesh, make up your mind already. Doing 2^24 times HMAC is perfectly possible on normal CPU's, so brute force the key. But goodness sake, I hope you are more precise during any exams or indeed on the job.